# How to use 'this' in an arrow function for referencing the clicked element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

**HTML**

```
<div class="sym-box" data-card="0">
    <div id="a"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
<div class="sym-box" data-card="1">
    <div id="b"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
<div class="sym-box" data-card="2">
    <div id="c"><img src="..."></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var attribute;

function myFunction() {
    attribute = this.getAttribute('data-card');
}

var symboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('sym-box');

for (i = 0; i < symboxes.length; i++) {
  symboxes[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

The code above works as expected, 'this' references the clicked element. However, when I write it as an arrow function I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function" because 'this' is now referring to the window object.

```
const myFunction = () => {
    attribute = this.getAttribute('data-card');
};
```

So my question is how do I rewrite myFunction() as an arrow function where 'this' refers to the clicked element?

**NOTE:**
My question has been marked as a duplicate but I am asking for a work around to achieve the same thing when using an arrow function. Just being told "You can't" or "Don't" didn't answer my question.

Comment: simple, you can't - arrow functions `this` is very clearly defined, and it can not be the clicked element

Comment: If for some reason you insist on using arrow syntax, use `event.currentTarget` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So my question is how do I rewrite myFunction() as an arrow function
>   where 'this' refers to the clicked element?

With `myFunction` defined as *arrow-function*, `this` refers to the *scope in which it is defined*.

Use `event.target` (in case you still want to use *arrow function*)

```
const myFunction = (event) => {
    attribute = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-card');
};
```

Comment: @Coffeebean If you did not use arrow function but a regular function `var myFunction = function()... ` then you could do it with `fun.bind` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) - . `symboxes[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction.bind(symboxes[i])`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0o1ujo4c/. But the answer posted solves the problem in a decent way.

Comment: You will want to use `.currentTarget`, not `.target`. Most likely the image will be clicked, and it doesn't have a `data-card` attribute.

Comment: @Bergi Yes you are right, the img is returned

Comment: @bergi made the change, thanks for highlighting the same.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override the `this` value of an arrow function. The `this` value for that arrow function would be taken from its execution context. Once it is bound, it cannot be replaced or overridden. This is the basic rule.

```
const myFunction = () => {
    attribute = this.getAttribute('data-card');
};
```

So here in your code, the `this` value available at the scope of myFunction variable declaration will be taken and bind to the function. The rule of thumb here is, **DON'T** use arrow function for event listeners.

You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: "The rule of thumb here is, DON'T use arrow function for event listeners." So how do you go about it when you need, in an even listener, to access both a class instance (where the listener is defined) and the target? Using an arrow function + `event.currentTarget` sounds like the right approach then.